# How are the gods forgotten?

Tags: granblue-fantasy

In Granblue Fantasy episode 4, the villain accuses the general populace of forgetting their goddess, to which he has provoked into causing a problem (I left it vague to keep out the spoilers).

How does a society "forget" living and active gods and goddesses?  In many works of art, I see that they old religion gets replaced by a new one.  Sometimes that new one is monothiestic.  I see no evidence of that in Granblue.

Comment: The intro from the game mentioned otherwise: gods abandoned​ the world, and thus an incident happened. Also I'm not sure if there is goddess (which?) mentioned​ in the game, until recently (after 3 years since the game's released, though they are called seraphim, not gods). Though, I haven't watched the anime yet...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played the game, but I am up to date with the anime. So I will use that as my source.

By what we have been told so far the gods weren't forgotten. They were simply neglected. The society was aware about their existence, but simply didn't worship them anymore. It most likely became a hassle as they became more and more independent from the "gods".

Most people were aware from stories told by the elder people that there was a temple, but they didn't care enough to actually check it out.